# How to run a portable executable in a docker on linux system

Tags: docker, portable-executable, ctf

I am working on a application to deploy challenges for ctfs.

I want to include windows service type challenges, too.

How can I deploy a Portable Executable file on a linux based server?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use docker to run Microsoft Windows. To run Windows executables on linux, you can try to use `wine` or rely on Virtualization (with a full windows installation inside).

You could also have a look at `.net for linux` to implement your challenge. This [article](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/net-linux) should get you started if this is what you chose.